# How to show hijri calendar in CalendarControl in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, html, hijri, calendar-control

I have a web page, using Asp.Net 4.0.

I have two calendar controls first for Georgian Calendar and second for hijri Calendar.

How can i show Hijri calendar in CalendarControl2 without changing my page's culter.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570197/ASP-NET-DatePicker-User-Control

Comment: isn't it possible in CalendarControl.